# Console C# program audio never plays

Tags: c#, audio, xamarin, monodevelop

I'm currently spending a bit of time making simple Console applications using Xamarin studio/monodevelop in C#. (On Mac OSX)

But for whatever reason, my audio code isn't working. A track never plays when the console opens, but I get no errors.
I'm sure the code is good:

```
using System;

using System.Media;

namespace Learnin
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            (new SoundPlayer(@"/Users/alasdairgorniak/Desktop/Take.wav")).PlaySync();
...
```

Comment: Have you compared with Winform or other platforms?

Comment: Sorry, What's Winform?

Comment: Anyone got an answer?

Comment: Are you developing on Windows? If on linux, `SoundPlayer` not work looks not strange to me.

Comment: Developing on Mac OS X

Comment: UPDATE: Code isn't to blame, having other issues with the Mac OS which have nothing to do with this. Thanks for the help